# Pairwise reshaping dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, graph

I am trying to build a list of graph edges from a two-column data frame representing one edge per node.

```
pd.DataFrame({'node': ['100',  '100', '200',  '200', '200'],
  'edge': ['111111',  '222222', '123456', '456789',  '987654']})
```

The result should look like this

```
pd.DataFrame({'node': ['100', '100','200',  '200', '200', '200', '200', '200'],
            'edge1': ['111111','222222','123456', '123456',  '456789', '456789', '987654', '987654'],
            'edge2': ['222222', '111111','456789', '987654',  '987654', '123456' , '123456','456789']})
```

I have been wrestling with pivot table and stack for a while but no success.

Comment: Show the wrestling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `itertools.permutations` to get the permutations of the edges after groupby, then convert the output to a new df to generate the desired output:

```
import pandas as pd
from itertools import permutations

df = pd.DataFrame({'node': ['100',  '100', '200',  '200', '200'],'edge': ['111111',  '222222', '123456', '456789',  '987654']})

df = df.groupby('node')['edge'].apply(list).apply(lambda x:list(permutations(x, 2))).reset_index().explode('edge')
pd.DataFrame(df["edge"].to_list(), index=df['node'], columns=['edge1', 'edge2']).reset_index()
```

Result:

|  | node | edge1 | edge2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 100 | 111111 | 222222 |
| 1 | 100 | 222222 | 111111 |
| 2 | 200 | 123456 | 456789 |
| 3 | 200 | 123456 | 987654 |
| 4 | 200 | 456789 | 123456 |
| 5 | 200 | 456789 | 987654 |
| 6 | 200 | 987654 | 123456 |
| 7 | 200 | 987654 | 456789 |